# how to set different value for same name data attribute from different element

Tags: jquery

I have following jquery click event

```
$(document).on('click', '.pagn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).data('page');
    var type = $(this).attr('id');
    if(page>0 && type == 'prev') {
        prev = page - 1;
        next = page + 1;
    } else if(type == 'next') {
        next = page - 1;
        prev = page + 1;
    }
    console.log(next);
    $('#next').data('page', next);
    $('#prev').data('page', prev);

})
```

Here is my html

```
<li><a id="prev" class="tools prev pagn" data-page='0'></a></li>
<li><a id="next" class="tools next pagn" data-page='2'></a></li>
```

In the above code I am unable to set values for data attributes value for the id next and prev.

How to resolve it

Comment: That code looks like it should basically work. It won't set the values of the `data-page` attributes on the elements, it just sets the information stored in jQuery's data cache for those elements. but since that's also what it reads, it should work. Just don't expect the attribute values to change (just the the values used by jQuery's `data`).

Comment: It's working fine for me. I can't see the changes on dom with firebug but when i try to get the page value from data-page it works fine.

Can you try putting:
console.log($('#next').data('page')); at the end of function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set `data-*` attributes, you use `attr`:

```
$('#next').attr('data-page', next);
$('#prev').attr('data-page', prev);
```

And similarly, if you want to read the attribute (rather than jQuery's data cache), use `attr` earlier when reading:

```
var page = $(this).attr('data-page');
```

jQuery's `data` function is really confusing to a lot of people. It does not manage `data-*` attributes. What it does is manage data associated with elements, and it *initializes* that data from any `data-*` attributes on the elements. That's the only connection: The initial value of a `data` field comes from a `data-*` attribute (if there is one). The `data` function never *writes* to `data-*` attributes.